# Attempt to index field a nil value

Tags: lua, null, garrys-mod

I play Garrys's Mod and i also run a addon on my Server. But the addon doesen't work. This is the Error:

[tperson] addons/tperson/lua/3tcore/client/cl_functions.lua:23: attempt to index field 'allow' (a nil value)

1. IsActive - addons/tperson/lua/3tcore/client/cl_functions.lua:23

The Code is the following:

```
 if not TPerson.HasPermission( pPlayer, "3rd", "allow" ) and TPerson.HasPermission( pPlayer, "1st", "allow" ) then return false end
    if pPlayer:InVehicle() then return false end
    if not playerConfig["allow"]["third"] then return false end
if not playerConfig["allow"]["tNearEntity"] and TPerson.IsNearOfEntity() then return false end
    if TPerson.IsHoldingWeapon() then return false end
    if TPerson.IsScopping() and not playerConfig["allow"]["tOnAiming"] then return false end

    return TActive
end
```

Please Help

Comment: "a addon"  and would you mind at least naming that addon?  provide a link
the error is pretty clear. in line 23 of cl_functions.lua you're indexing a nil value, field "allow". don't do that or make sure the field is not nil.

Comment: It seems like `playerConfig` is missing `allow` field